# Как сделать текст непрозрачным на фоне div который становится прозрачным при наведении?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть дивы в которых есть круг (тоже див):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

который становится видимым только при наведении, и текст внутри:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя задача это чтобы текст при наведении не был полупрозрачным, как круг внутри которого он находится, а обычным. По какой-то причине текст внутри дива `inner-circle` принимает все его свойства, хоть я и задал отдельно для текста свойство `opacity: 1;` при наведении.

```css
#outer-circle1 {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuXam.jpg');
  background-position: 4px 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  background: #a9aaab;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -75px 0px 0px -75px;
}

#inner-circle:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5px;
  visibility:  hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#inner-circle:hover .text {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-circle1">
  <div id="inner-circle"><p class="text"><br/><br/>More</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я подправил вам сниппет, чтобы он хоть что-то отображал. Можете его доправить, чтобы стили "не полезли"? А то картинка как-то сильно вылазит.

Comment: Наверное, лучше сделать для  `#outer-circle1` `background-position: center;`.

Comment: Благодарю! Почему то как ни пробовал текст отображался криво. Сейчас отлично.

Comment: Кстати, ещё можно заменить `margin: -75px 0px 0px -75px;` на `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`. Это позволит вам менять гибко `width` и `height`, не трогая `margin` (устанавливая половину высоты и ширины).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы `opacity` не наследовался другими элементми, вместо `opacity` установите `background-color` через `rgba`, где устанавливайте прозрачность в компоненте `a`. То есть вместо `opacity: 0.4;` пишите `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);` (это полупрозрачный белый).
Также исправил некоторые другие шероховатости этой разметки:

```css
#outer-circle1 {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuXam.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  background: #a9aaab;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate(-4px, -1px);
}

#inner-circle:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5px;
  visibility:  hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#inner-circle:hover .text {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-circle1">
  <div id="inner-circle"><p class="text"><br/><br/>More</p></div>
</div>
```

#### UPDATE

Чтобы также совмещать фиксированные величины и проценты можете

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

заменить на

```
transform: translate(calc(-4px - 50%), calc(-1px - 50%));
```

либо на

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate(-4px, -1px);
```

Comment: Благодарю, теперь всё стало как надо, причина по которой я установил background-position как 4px 1px это то, что круг на фоновом изображении находится не совсем по центру, и чтобы при наведении див вписывался точно в круг я таким образом подправил. Теперь всё работает, скажите а что означает transform: translate(-50%, -50%)?

Comment: Это означает перенести элемент отностильно своих же размеров на 50% ширины по осям X и 50% высоты по осям Y. А вы поиграйтесь с разными параметрами и всё наглядней поймёте. Пока не попробуете, легко забудется.

Comment: @Adonxx Обновил ответ по поводу совмещение процентов и фиксированных величин в `transform`. Очень советую вам изучить это свойство. Там вы можете помимо перемещения также вращать и масштабировать элементы в неограниченном кол-ве за один присест.

Comment: Спасибо вам, очень помогли! Обязательно учту всё что вы сказали.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#outer-circle1 {
background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuXam.jpg);
transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);//сделает замедление 
}
#outer-circle1:hover {
background-image:(путь к твоей картинки при наведении);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-circle1">
  <div id="inner-circle"><p class="text"><br/><br/>More</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: -1 А почему нельзя на конкретном примере показать результат? Почему надо писать какой-то абстрактный алгоритм?

Comment: так как код с ошибкой который дан в примере

Comment: Код уже исправлен, я отредактировал до вашего ответа.